# faultstring Says "A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present", Where did I go wrong?

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, oracle-integration-cloud

When I make the same request over SOAP UI application, I have to tick "Generate Random MessageID", and then it works.

But when I am trying to make this request in Oracle Integration cloud (OIC), Integration, I get the below fault message.
I have given Basic authentication and created a custom header to substitute the "Generate Random MessageID" option as in SOAP UI.

I searched in the WSDL file from which this holdRequest operation gets picked, I dont see any element named MessageID

Received the below fault message:

```
Fault:<soap-env:Fault xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <faultcode xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap:Server</faultcode>
  <faultstring>A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present</faultstring>
  <detail>
    <ICSfaultVar />
    <reason>CASDK-0033: Received a SOAP fault while invoking endpoint target: https://fa.oraclecloud.com:443/ess/esswebservice. This indicates a processing exception on the service endpoint side. Please check service side logs to further diagnose the problem &lt;![CDATA[ Fault Code : wsa:MessageAddressingHeaderRequired Fault String : A required header representing a Message Addressing Property is not present ]]&gt; :Application Error</reason>
    <operation>holdRequest</operation>
    <request_payload />
  </detail>
</soap-env:Fault>
```

I hope some of your expert eye could help me. Thanks